# How do I execute Navigator.of(context).pop() when the state doesn't return an error in BLoC?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm building a very simple 2FA application, which scans a QR code and then it shows the TOTP code on the screen. However, I don't know how to go back to previous screen using Navigator.of(context).pop(). When I do that in my app, it crashes.

Here's a short video how my app reacts to this: https://streamable.com/ao6qql

How do I check if the form is empty? If it is, I want to show the Alert Dialog, but it returns to the previous screen and it is showing the AlertDialog. How do I do it so my Navigator.of(context).pop() executes when the form is filled?

### Code:

#### The block which crashes my app:

```
BlocListener<ManualInputBloc, ManualInputState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is ManualInputError) {
                Platform.isAndroid
                    ? CustomAlertDialog.showAndroidAlertDialog(
                        context,
                        state.alertDialogErrorTitle,
                        state.alertDialogErrorContent,
                      )
                    : CustomAlertDialog.showIosAlertDialog(
                        context,
                        state.alertDialogErrorTitle,
                        state.alertDialogErrorContent,
                      );
              }
            },
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final manualInputBloc =
                    BlocProvider.of<ManualInputBloc>(context);

                manualInputBloc.add(
                  GetFormTextEvent(
                    secretKey,
                    issuer,
                    accountName,
                    numberOfDigits,
                    timeStep,
                  ),
                );

                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('add').tr(),
            ),
          )
```

#### The whole screen:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:duckie/blocs/manual_input/manual_input_bloc.dart';
import 'package:duckie/screens/widgets/alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:duckie/screens/widgets/custom_text_field.dart';
import 'package:duckie/shared/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class ManualInputScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ManualInputScreenState createState() => _ManualInputScreenState();
}

class _ManualInputScreenState extends State<ManualInputScreen> {
  String secretKey;
  String issuer;
  String accountName;
  String numberOfDigits = '6';
  String timeStep = '30';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'manual-input',
          style: TextStyles.appBarText,
        ).tr(),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: [
          BlocListener<ManualInputBloc, ManualInputState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is ManualInputError) {
                Platform.isAndroid
                    ? CustomAlertDialog.showAndroidAlertDialog(
                        context,
                        state.alertDialogErrorTitle,
                        state.alertDialogErrorContent,
                      )
                    : CustomAlertDialog.showIosAlertDialog(
                        context,
                        state.alertDialogErrorTitle,
                        state.alertDialogErrorContent,
                      );
              }
            },
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final manualInputBloc =
                    BlocProvider.of<ManualInputBloc>(context);

                manualInputBloc.add(
                  GetFormTextEvent(
                    secretKey,
                    issuer,
                    accountName,
                    numberOfDigits,
                    timeStep,
                  ),
                );

                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('add').tr(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            CustomTextField(
              labelText: 'secret-key'.tr(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  secretKey = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            CustomTextField(
              labelText: 'issuer'.tr(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                issuer = value;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            CustomTextField(
              labelText: 'account-name'.tr(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  accountName = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Platform.isAndroid
                ? ListBody(
                    children: [
                      Text('number-of-digits').tr(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      DropdownButton(
                        value: numberOfDigits,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            numberOfDigits = value;
                          });
                        },
                        items: [
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: '6',
                            child: Text('6'),
                          ),
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: '8',
                            child: Text('8'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                : ListBody(
                    children: [
                      Text('number-of-digits').tr(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                        groupValue: numberOfDigits,
                        children: {
                          '6': Text('6'),
                          '8': Text('8'),
                        },
                        onValueChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            numberOfDigits = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Platform.isAndroid
                ? ListBody(
                    children: [
                      Text('time-step').tr(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      DropdownButton(
                        value: timeStep,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            timeStep = value;
                          });
                        },
                        items: [
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: '30',
                            child: Text('30'),
                          ),
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: '60',
                            child: Text('60'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                : ListBody(
                    children: [
                      Text('time-step').tr(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                        groupValue: timeStep,
                        children: {
                          '30': Text('30'),
                          '60': Text('60'),
                        },
                        onValueChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            timeStep = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "When I do that in my app, it crashes." - Please post the stack trace. Also, please clarify what you'd like to ask. Currently, the title implies a different question than the content, ie. "How do I check if the form is empty?", etc.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I fixed the title.